# How can I extract image from a website into my rails project?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Ruby on rails. I am making a web application in which I have to fetch RSS feeds from news websites, which I have done using gem feedzirra. I was thinking of extracting images from every feed url and posting it on my application. But I don't know which gem will be suitable for just extracting images from different websites. I thought of using nokogiri or opengraph but I don't know how to go about it. Can someone please guide me. Thank you

I want to do something like this :

```
 <% @feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml") %>
 <% @feed.inspect %> 
 <% @entries = @feed.entries %>
 <% for i in 0..9 %> 
 <br>
 <b><u><%= @entries[i].title %></u></b>
 </br>
 <br>
 **<%= get image from @entries[i].url %> \\ how can i do this ?**
 </br>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Extracting images from every feed could put you squarely in a copyright violation, which can be very costly. Think carefully about that. Also, do NOT put that logic in a view. It needs to be in a controller where its pre-processed, with only the ready-to-use data being passed into the view. If you put it in a view, it will cause that user's browser to hang while your code attempts to retrieve the information from some distant site. Your app, and their display, will hang until it completes. It'd also be a swell way to DOS your system by slowing the response way down.

Comment: Thanks I'll move the code to controller.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using [ActionView `image_tag` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag), which would create a html `img` tag to an external url in this case:

```
...
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <%= entry.title %>
  <%= image_tag(entry.url) %>
<% end %>
```

Also, please take into consideration more Rubyish way to iterate through Array elements, which I presented above.

If you would like to iterate through first 10 elements, instead of the whole array (like in your example) you could do it in the following way:

```
<% @entries[0..9].each do |entry| %>
  <%= entry.title %>
  <%= image_tag(entry.url) %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit:**

It seems like you can get img tag from the entry summary using Nokogiri, haven't tested it myself but you should check this blog post:
http://verboselogging.com/2009/05/24/rss-fun-with-feedzirra

Comment: Thank you your answer. I did exactly what you said, but still there is no image being displayed. Actually when we pass entry.url to image_tag, it does not recognize the image in the url and so it doesn't display it. I think we'll have to pass the link of the image to image_tag, but how to get that ?

Comment: Well, you're right, that's how `image_tag` works. I assumed that entry.url stores the direct link to the image, that's the only way to get it work this way (for example `<%= image_tag 'http://example.com/pic.jpg' %>`).

Comment: I edited my answer, please try using Nokogiri to get the img tag following the blog post I included above.